# Ms-Excel selecting range on basis of month

Tags: excel

I have a column where only month number is displayed (till 12). I want to count user id month wise, so I used "=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$100,$B2)" But for this I selected only month 1. How to make the selected range dynamic such that all months upto 12 can be included and I get the user id count month wise?

[image]

Comment: What is your excel version? You can use `COUNTIFS()` to add another argument for month column like `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$100,$B2,$C$2:$C$100,$C2)`.

Comment: I am using Excel 365. And thanks, that worked! :)

Comment: I have posted the formula as answer. You may accept it (tick mark the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get count of user id month wise, use `COUNTIFS()` function to include month column as argument. Try-

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$100,$B2,$C$2:$C$100,$C2)
```